# Android FileProvider.GetUriForFile is cutting off the start of the URI

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-fileprovider

I'm trying to update my code which gets the database file. I'm trying to use a [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) instead.

I'm a bit stuck because the original file path is `"/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abc/files/abcMobile.db3”`

I need to get the URI which is returned by `FileProvider.GetUriForFile` to include "/storage/emulated/0/“ at the start of it.

Here is my code:

```
Log.Info ("directory", GetDirectory (dir).ToString());
                Log.Info ("filename", filename);
                File newFile = new File (GetDirectory (dir).AbsolutePath, "/" + filename);
                Android.Net.Uri androidContentUri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile (Application.Context, Application.Context.PackageName + ".fileprovider", newFile);
                System.Uri systemContentUri = SystemUri (androidContentUri);
                return systemContentUri;
```

In the code above I have created a file which has a path of `"/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abc/files/abcMobile.db3”` but when I pass the file to `FileProvider.GetUriForFile()` It seems to create an Android.Net.URI of  `{content://com.abc.fileprovider/./Android/data/com.abc/files/abcMobile.db3}` and I cast it to a `System.Net.URI` which becomes `{content://com.abc.fileprovider/Android/data/com.abc/files/abcMobile.db3}`.

I just need to figure out why it deletes `"/storage/emulated/0/“` from the start of the `Android.Net.Uri` and stop that from happening and then it should work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just need to figure out why it deletes "/storage/emulated/0/“ from the start of the Android.Net.Uri and stop that from happening and then it should work. Any ideas?

Because you are generating content uri for your file,which grant temporary permission for access to this file. Return a full path of the file is not considered to be a secure way.

And if you are refer to "Generating the Content URI for a File" section of [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html). You will find the following sentence:

> To share a file with another app using a content URI, your app has to generate the content URI.
>
> ...
>
> As a result of the previous snippet, getUriForFile() returns the content URI content://com.mydomain.fileprovider/my_images/default_image.jpg.

So, it is a expected form of ContentUri that returned by `FileProvider`.